# How to exclude values in a Phabricator query

Tags: phabricator

For example, I need to get all Maniphest tasks that are assigned to **not** me. Can I achieve it in Phabricator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature doesn't currently exist.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe you know, is there any threads where I can track progress on this functionality? Actually, I cannot figure out where is the bug tracker for Phabricator itself.

Comment: Googling "phabricator support" returns the right result, first link, FWIW.

Comment: https://secure.phabricator.com/T4444 feature request marked as wontfix

Comment: Filter out matches with minus: -mysearch.